# How to get the first value from pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a program to discretize a set of attributes via entropy discretization. The goal is to parse the dataset

```
A,Class
5,1
12.5,1
11.5,2
8.6,2
7,1
6,1
5.9,2
1.5,2
9,2
7.8,1
2.1,1
13.5,2
12.45,2
```

Into

```
A,Class
1,1
3,1
3,2
2,2
2,1
2,1
1,2
1,2
3,2
2,1
1,1
3,2
3,2
```

The specific problem that I am facing with my program is determining the number of classes in my dataset. This takes place at `numberOfClasses = s['Class'].value_counts()`. I would like to use a pandas method to return the number of distinct classes. In this example there are only two. However I get back

```
Number of classes: 2    5
1    4
```

From the print statement.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import entropy_based_binning as ebb
from math import log2

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('S1.csv')
    s = df
    s = entropy_discretization(s)

# This method discretizes s A1
# If the information gain is 0, i.e the number of 
# distinct class is 1 or
# If min f/ max f < 0.5 and the number of distinct values is floor(n/2)
# Then that partition stops splitting.
def entropy_discretization(s):

    informationGain = {}
    # while(uniqueValue(s)):
    # Step 1: pick a threshold
    threshold = 6

    # Step 2: Partititon the data set into two parttitions
    s1 = s[s['A'] < threshold]
    print("s1 after spitting")
    print(s1)
    print("******************")
    s2 = s[s['A'] >= threshold]
    print("s2 after spitting")
    print(s2)
    print("******************")
        
    # Step 3: calculate the information gain.
    informationGain = information_gain(s1,s2,s)

    print(informationGain)

    # # Step 5: calculate the max information gain
    # minInformationGain = min(informationGain)

    # # Step 6: keep the partitions of S based on the value of threshold_i
    # s = bestPartition(minInformationGain, s)

def uniqueValue(s):
    # are records in s the same? return true
    if s.nunique()['A'] == 1:
        return False
    # otherwise false 
    else:
        return True

def bestPartition(maxInformationGain):
    # determine be threshold_i
    threshold_i = 6

    return 


def information_gain(s1, s2, s):
    # calculate cardinality for s1
    cardinalityS1 = len(pd.Index(s1['A']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s1 is: {cardinalityS1}')
    # calculate cardinality for s2
    cardinalityS2 = len(pd.Index(s2['A']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s2 is: {cardinalityS2}')
    # calculate cardinality of s
    cardinalityS = len(pd.Index(s['A']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s is: {cardinalityS}')
    # calculate informationGain
    informationGain = (cardinalityS1/cardinalityS) * entropy(s1) + (cardinalityS2/cardinalityS) * entropy(s2)
    print(f'The total informationGain is: {informationGain}')
    return informationGain



def entropy(s):
    # calculate the number of classes in s
    numberOfClasses = s['Class'].value_counts()
    print(f'Number of classes: {numberOfClasses}')
    # TODO calculate pi for each class.
    # calculate the frequency of class_i in S1
    p1 = 2/4
    p2 = 3/4
    ent = -(p1*log2(p2)) - (p2*log2(p2))

    return ent 

main()
```

Ideally, I'd like to print `Number of classes: 2`. This way I can loop over the classes and calculate the frequencies for the attribute `A` from the dataset. I've reviewed the pandas documentation, but I got stuck at `value_counts()`. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
number_of_classes = len(s['Class'].unique())
```

which will return the number of unique classes in the column `Class`.

Or even shorter:

```
s['Class'].nunique()
```